# What's the recommended way to iterate SCANs in Lua for Redis?

Tags: lua, redis

I've been looking around for the recommended way to iterate over SCANs using Lua and was wondering if there was a "best practice" so to speak for it. The script below was the best I could find so far. Does anyone have anything to add? Is it wise to iterate using COUNT 1000000000? Wouldn't that be blocking?

```
local ans, has, cursor = {}, {}, "0";
repeat
    local t = redis.call("SCAN", cursor, "MATCH", KEYS[1], "COUNT", 1000000000);
    local list = t[2];
    for i = 1, #list do
        local s = list[i];
        if has[s] == nil then has[s] = 1; ans[#ans + 1] = s; end;
    end;
    cursor = t[1];
until cursor == "0";
return #ans; --or return ans;
```

Taken from: https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/3190#issuecomment-214022437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script will block while it is running and until it ends - in your example that will happen once `SCAN`ning is complete. The bigger the `COUNT` hint to the `SCAN` command, the more results each call to it will return, resulting in more RAM needed for storing the reply (the variable `t`). This could lead to an out of memory condition, so you should refrain from using such large `COUNT` values. I recommend sticking with the default (100), and just omitting the `COUNT` hint.

Comment: So the script is atomic and blocking, so the only concern is that COUNT might use up a lot of RAM. Thanks Itamar.